# How can I improve these controller code to make has_many through database design better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following are my models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_categoryships
    has_many :categories, :through => :item_categoryships

    belongs_to :user

    validates :title, presence: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_categoryships
    has_many :items, :through => :item_categoryships

    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, presence: true
end


class ItemCategoryship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :category
    validates :item_id, presence: true
    validates :category_id, presence: true
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
    has_many :categories, class_name: 'Category'
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :async
end
```

In my Item controller, there are these code:

```
def edit
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    @categories = current_user.categories
end

def update
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])

    if @item.update_attributes(item_params) 
            params[:item][:category_ids].map{|x| x.to_i }.each do |category_id|
                category = ItemCategoryship.new(item_id: @item.id, category_id: category_id)
                category.save unless category.category_id <= 0
            end

            flash[:success] = "item updated successfully!"      
            redirect_to items_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

My **views/items/edit.html.erb** :

```
    <%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :title, :label => "title" %>
            <%= f.input :description, :as => :text, :label => "description" %>
            <%= f.select :category_ids, @categories.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
            <%= f.submit 'submit', class: 'btn bnt-large btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

I want database can only have what user selected, if user selected two categories, then ItemCategoryship table just have two records, if user cancel one of them, then that record destroyed from table.

How can I improve my code to implement this function in concise way?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be enough no need to add ItemCategoryShip seperately.

```
def update
    @item = current_user.items.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update_attributes(param[:item])    
      flash[:success] = "item updated successfully!"      
      redirect_to items_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Comment: Cool~~ What is the magic behind this? Can you explain for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually in above case, you can directly assign the category_ids eg: @item.category_ids = [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Why just passed category_ids in, it know what I want? If I select all, it will save all to database, if I cancel some of them, they will be destroyed from database, if there are any official documents or posts about the rule of this magic? I want to know it more. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Checkout RAILSCAST: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast